# Why am I receiving a Route Collection error when inserting data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

When I try to insert data in Laravel 5.3 below error shown

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 755
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

**My Controller Code**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\userCreate;

public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $newUser = new userCreate;

        $newUser ->fname = $request->fname;
        $newUser ->lname = $request->lname;
        $newUser ->email = $request->email;
        $newUser ->password = $request->password;
        $newUser ->utype = $request->utype;

        $newUser->save();

       //return redirect('/');
    }
```

I'll look to post my route here:

Comment: Please show the route and how do you send data to `store()`

Comment: its related to your route only probably you are hitting the wrong method like you might have defined post method for a route and trying to use get Method on it or viceversa...Consider posting your routes.php and how you are calling your route

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your method is POST when accessing the route that creates a new user.

Answer (score 1):

Try it...I think you are using resource controller so routing may be fine.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\userCreate;

public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $newUser = new userCreate;

        $newUser ->fname = $request->input('fname');
        $newUser ->lname = $request->input('lname');
        $newUser ->email = $request->input('email');
        $newUser ->password = $request->input('password');
        $newUser ->utype = $request->input('utype');

        $newUser->save();

       //return redirect('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use POST method when accessing the route that creates a new user.

```
Route::post('/store',    'NameController@store');
```

Answer (score 1):

your route should be as below :

```
Route::resource('store','ControllerName');
```

if still not working, add your `routes.php` to Question.